# Uneven Height of grid items

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

**See i'am using Tailwind CSS V3 and i cant set the even height of grid items, the grid items get the same height only if i give them a height of `h-96`. If i use break points like `lg:h-80` and `md:h-96` then i get the same uneven height issue.**

Here's the code of my section:

```html
<!--! Service Section -->
<section class="bg-slate-900 text-white py-16">
  <div>
    <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold text-center text-gray-100 mb-4">Our Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div class=" md:grid-flow-col grid lg:grid-rows-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">

    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Web Development</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">We develop custom, responsive websites tailored to your business needs using the latest technologies and best practices.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-palette"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Graphic Design</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">Our team of designers creates stunning visual assets, including logos, branding materials, brochures, and more, that help your business stand out from the competition.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Mobile Development</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">We build mobile apps for iOS and Android that are not only visually stunning but also provide an intuitive and engaging user experience.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-search"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">SEO Optimization</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">Our SEO experts ensure that your website ranks higher in search engine results, driving more traffic and potential customers to your business.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-server"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Server Administration</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">We provide server administration services to ensure that your website is running smoothly and efficiently, with minimal downtime and maximum security.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="p-8 bg-slate-800 rounded-lg shadow-lg h-96 md:h-80 m-4">
        <i class="text-5xl mb-4 fas fa-cogs"></i>
        <h3 class="text-xl font-bold mb-4">IT Consulting</h3>
        <p class="text-gray-400 leading-loose">Our team of IT experts provides consulting services to help your business make the best use of technology, from identifying opportunities for automation to implementing security protocols.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want the grid items to have a same height using `breakpoints`.

Comment: I've edited your question, converting the posted HTML to a running stack-snippet; while I initially added a link to the Tailwind CSS I mistakenly linked to v2.x, and so I removed that. Would you be able to add a link to a relevant source?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code with the fix:

```html
<div class="bg-slate-900">
    <section class="mx-auto max-w-5xl px-4 py-16 text-white">
        <div>
            <h2 class="mb-4 text-center text-3xl font-bold text-gray-100">Our Services</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="grid justify-center gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 [&>*]:max-w-lg">
            <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-laptop-code mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">Web Development</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">We develop custom, responsive websites tailored to your business needs using the latest technologies and best practices.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-palette mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">Graphic Design</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">Our team of designers creates stunning visual assets, including logos, branding materials, brochures, and more, that help your business stand out from the competition.</p>
            </div>
                <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">Mobile Development</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">We build mobile apps for iOS and Android that are not only visually stunning but also provide an intuitive and engaging user experience.</p>
            </div>
                <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-search mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">SEO Optimization</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">Our SEO experts ensure that your website ranks higher in search engine results, driving more traffic and potential customers to your business.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-server mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">Server Administration</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">We provide server administration services to ensure that your website is running smoothly and efficiently, with minimal downtime and maximum security.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="m-4 rounded-lg bg-slate-800 p-8 shadow-lg">
                <i class="fas fa-cogs mb-4 text-5xl"></i>
                <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-bold">IT Consulting</h3>
                <p class="leading-loose text-gray-400">Our team of IT experts provides consulting services to help your business make the best use of technology, from identifying opportunities for automation to implementing security protocols.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Documentation URL: [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#using-custom-breakpoints)

Discord Link for further informations: https://discord.gg/tailwind to get support

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).